# Can't access BIOS after BIOS update via the Dell update utility

Tags: windows-10, bios, dell-inspiron

I used the Dell update utility to update my BIOS. After reboot, the Dell logo did not appear and I could not access the BIOS by repeatedly pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>. There was also no message to indicate which function key must be pressed to access the BIOS.

What should I do at this point? How do I access the BIOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the procedure Microsoft recommends in
[Boot to UEFI Mode or legacy BIOS mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/boot-to-uefi-mode-or-legacy-bios-mode?view=windows-11):

> from either the Sign on screen or the Start menu, select **Power** ([image]) > hold **Shift** while selecting **Restart**. Select **Troubleshoot > Advanced options > UEFI Firmware settings**.

If this doesn't work, you will need to force-install the previous
BIOS/UEFI version. More information is required about your computer
model and the BIOS version you had before and have now.